# Codeigniter Image Manipulation Class process overhead

Tags: apache, codeigniter, image-processing, imagemagick

in Codeigniter's Image Manipulation Class there's a preference called 'library_path' where you have to mention the path to the binary. this means its executing the binary. Does this take more ram than using the apache extension ?

is there a less process intensive class or a method that can be used with CI?

Comment: Library_path is not required if you have the GD or GD2 extension installed.

Comment: When i do this it says "Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image. JPG images are not supported."

Comment: In that case you must enable/install the php GD extension, where is your site hosted?

Comment: I have the latest GD2 and its showing up in phpinfo()
The image re sizing works fine but now cropping isnt working.

Comment: Are you doing the resize and crop in the same function?

Comment: No they are done in different functions. I figured it out anyway thanks. The GD problem was coz when cropping i have to define the width and height as well (for imagick you dont need this). Im now using gd extention.

The imagick question is still there. If anybody knows of a good php library that does not use @shell (which is used in CI as well) please post here. thanks